# Magento 2 Dynamic Arrays in new tab of customer edit section

Tags: magento2

How to show a "Dynamic Array" in new tab of customer edit section in admin Magento 2 as in screen shot below.

[image]

On clicking on the new tab sya "custom Tab", I need to show a Dynamic array like

[image]

Comment: Frontend or backend & which page?

Comment: @AnkitShah , on admin section.

Comment: @AnkitShah , please have a look on the question now. I have updated my question

Comment: @JulienLachal, I have created a new module and created a new tab in the customer edit section using "customer_index_edit" section. But now I am confused to show the Dynamic arrays. I have go through the Tire pricing creation module but couldn't understand what to do.

Comment: I can see that some answers like [link] http://blog.belvg.com/dynamic-settings-array-in-magento-2-0.html and [link]http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-guide-to-create-table-setting-in-the-system-configuration but I don't think that I can use the system.xml to do this